# MySQL: select last row of each pair

Tags: php, mysql

I have a little problem to solve, but I can't. I have the following `chat` table:

```
id      user    friend      msg                     date
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1       1       2           Hello Bob!              2014-07-04 01:00
2       1       2           How are you doing?      2014-07-04 01:01
3       2       1           I'm fine bro!           2014-07-04 02:30
4       1       3           Hey Mark :D             2014-07-04 02:31
5       3       1           Yo!                     2014-07-04 02:32
6       4       1           Wassup?!                2014-07-04 07:00
```

I'm working on a PHP `getInbox($uid)` method that returns an array of the last message of each pair (user and friend). I tried a `SELECT` query with `GROUP BY friend`, but it is incomplete.

```
SELECT * FROM `chat`
GROUP BY `friend` 
WHERE `user` = $uid OR `friend` = $uid
```

The desired result is:

```
id      user    friend      msg                     date
----------------------------------------------------------------------
3       2       1           I'm fine bro!           2014-07-04 02:30
5       3       1           Yo!                     2014-07-04 02:32
6       4       1           Wassup?!                2014-07-04 07:00
```

I would appreciate a help!

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you had some kind of "thread" or "conversation" identifier. A simple approach is to set the "parent" of all replies to be the first in the chain, then select the last in each chain.

Comment: so I'm guessing `4,1,3` is a message to "mark", and then `5,3,1` is mark's reply?

Comment: I thought about it, create a table `conversations` and set a foreign key on each chat row . But I want to try with a single table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT c.* FROM
chat c
JOIN
(SELECT
    max(id) max_id,
    (CASE WHEN user < friend THEN user ELSE friend END) user_a,
    (CASE WHEN user < friend THEN friend ELSE user END) user_b
FROM chat
    GROUP BY user_a, user_b) t1 ON t1.max_id = c.id
```

The case statements select (user,friend) in ascending order. For example, both (1,2) and (2,1) will be converted to (1,2). An ordered pair uniquely identifies a conversation. Finally, the latest id is selected for each ordered pair and rows having those ids are displayed from the chat table.

Comment: It works! Thanks. Could you add some comments, or explain your logic, please?